# Change ObjectBox LiveData Query

Tags: android, android-livedata, objectbox

I have an `ObjectBoxLiveData` object with a query that is set at runtime:

```
private ObjectBoxLiveData<MyObject> myObjectLiveData;
public ObjectBoxLiveData<MyObject> getMyObjectLiveData(Box<MyObject> myObjectBox, String filterTerm)
{
    if (myObjectLiveData == null)
        myObjectLiveData = new ObjectBoxLiveData<>(myObjectBox.query().equal(MyObject_.filterProperty, filterTerm).build());
    return myObjectLiveData;
}
```

But I also need to be able to change the `filterTerm` at runtime. My thinking is that I can make a `private String currentFilterTerm;` object in `MyViewModel` to see if I need to update the filter term in the LiveData object, but is there a correct way to update the filter term? I worry that setting `myObjectLiveData = new ObjectBoxLiveData<>` again will leave a memory leak for the previously defined `myObjectLiveData` or anything tied to it, but I don't see any graceful way to dispose of it or update the query once defined. Is there a way to redefine my query once defined?

Comment: Is there a reason why you think there will be a memory leak? If you do myObjectLiveData = new ObjectBoxLiveData<>, it will not result in a memory leak since no reference for the previous myObjectLiveData exists. (I am assuming myObjectLiveData is not copied anywhere else) The Java GC will automatically collect it when it needs to.

Comment: I think my worry is that there might be observers watching it, but I suppose that's not going to be an issue if I only ever set it from one location. I don't know, I'm new ot the lifecycle management stuff and it's giving me a headache.